# SignalR user is not registered in Client.Users

Tags: .net, signalr

I am creating a chat between 2 users.
Here's my hub and hub client:

```
public class ConversationHub : Hub<IConversationHubClient>
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var id = this.Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        //when I breakpoint here, I can see the id of my connected user.
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}

public interface IConversationHubClient
{
    void MessageReceived(string conversationId, 
        string userId, 
        string text, 
        DateTime date, 
        bool isUser);
}
```

And from the mvc controller, I am calling:

```
string userId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();
_conversationHub.Clients
            .User(userId)
            .MessageReceived(model.ConversationId, userId , model.Text, model.Date, true);
//I want to send back the message to the user, for testing purposes
```

And finally here is the front-end:

```
var conversationhub = $.connection.conversationHub;

//messageReceived
conversationhub.client.MessageReceived = function (conversationId, userId, text, sentOn, isUser){
        alert(':D');
    };
```

I am expecting to see the alert when I trigger my mvc controller method but nothing happens. It seems to me that the user is not registered in the connected users but I don't understand why and how to register it. Can someone help me on that?

Comment: What also worked for me is Clients.User(Context.UserIdentifier) instead of Context.User.Identity.GetUserId().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out it didn't work because of the way I was injecting the hubContext on my MVC Controller.

I followed the article on [SignalR DI with ninject](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

My binding was wrong. After following the example, I change my binding to:

```
   this.Kernel.Bind<IHubContext<IConversationHubClient>>()
            .ToMethod(x => GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>()
               .GetHubContext<ConversationHub, IConversationHubClient>());
```

And everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

`User.Identity.GetUserId()` does not equal `Context.ConnectionId`, which is what you need to call a specific client. It identifies SignalR connections. 
You need to map the users to connections. I suggest you take a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) tutorial:

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shinzon. Yes i know that userId is different than connectionId. I forgot to mention that I implemented an IUserIdProvider which returns the userId. I initially thought that by doing that, I will be able to call my methods with the signature ctx.Clients.User(userId) but it does not work.

Comment: Your Answer seems incorrect. The tutorial you link to says that in fact a default UserId Provider is automatically registered, if you register nothing yourself. And that provider SHOULD allow you to simply connect to a given user with Clients.User(userId), where userId in this case is IPrincipal.Identity.Name, which in Asp.Net Identity is UserName (not User.Id). But like K.L. I cannot get this to work. Client.All sends, Client.User(anything) does not

Comment: I was able to get Clients.User(Context.UserIdentifier) to work to send to all connections for the current user using the default identity management built into the ASP.NET core app (in my case cookie based authentication, similar to the old forms authentication cookies).

Answer (score 0):

I could never get `.Users` in SignalR to work. It purportedly maps to Asp.Net Authorization's IPrincipal but none of what you would expect to see for properties if so, is present.

Instead, I inserted the Asp.Net Identity UserId into a Claim, and then parsed it out into a very small in-memory dictionary, mapping UserIds to SignalR ClientIds. It's a hack but it works.

```
[Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Authorize]
public class MessageHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
{
    public static void ServerSend(PrivateMessage message)
    {
        var messageHub = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost
            .ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>();
        var clients = messageHub.Clients;

        var vm = MessageViewModel.From(message);

        var toId = message
            .ToId;
            //.FromId;  // Loopback for testing

        var toSignalRId = (string)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("signalr$" + toId);
        if (toSignalRId != null)
        {
            clients
                .Client(toSignalRId)
                //.All  // Broadcast for testing
                .sendChat(vm);
        }
    }



    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var context = this.Context;
        object identity = context.User.Identity;
        if (identity is System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)
        {
            var idClaim = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)context.User.Identity).Claims
                .Where(c => c.Type == ReducedClaims.DbGuidClaimsKey)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (idClaim == null)
                return base.OnConnected();

            string userId = idClaim.Value;
            var signalRconnectionId = context.ConnectionId;

            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("signalr$" + userId, signalRconnectionId, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
        }

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get Clients.User(Context.UserIdentifier) to work to send to all connections for the current user using the default identity management built into the ASP.NET core app (in my case cookie based authentication, similar to the old forms authentication cookies).