# Using SignalR just for just a user's session

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

I have a progress bar logic that implements SignalR on a page that processes uploaded file. It works properly and produces correct progress.

However, it produces progress bar for ALL users, not just for the user that uploaded the file. In other words, one user uploads the file, but that progress for that file upload shows even on screens of other user/sessions that conducted no action on their ends

I did come up with a workaround, where I send a user id with the SignalR progress call/signal and compare it with the user id stored in a hidden field on aspx. If they don't match, I don't produce the progress bar. However, this fix seems to be like a dirty workaround.

Is there a more efficient way to ensure the SignalR to work only within one session?

Just in case here is my code

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection attachments = null;
    try
    {

        lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;
```

> ```
>         var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
>
>         hubContext.Clients.All.AddProgress("Upload has been initiated: ", string.Empty, "0", 
>             Context.User.Identity.Name, pageName);
> ```

```
        if (fileupload1.HasFile)
        {
            attachments = Request.Files;
            if (attachments.Count > totalnumberoffiles)
            {
                lblMessage.Text += "Please select only " + totalnumberoffiles + " files.";
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                double fileProgressPercentagePortion = 100 / attachments.Count;
                double fileProgressPercentage = 0;
                double fileProgressPercentageSegment = fileProgressPercentagePortion/6;
                for (int i = 0; i < attachments.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile attachment = attachments[i];

                    if (attachment.FileName == string.Empty)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    hubContext.Clients.All.AddProgress("Currently processing: ", new System.IO.FileInfo(attachment.FileName).Name, "0", 
                        Context.User.Identity.Name, pageName);
                    if (attachment.ContentLength > 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment.FileName))
                    {
                        hubContext.Clients.Client(hubContext.co).AddProgress("Currently processing: ", new System.IO.FileInfo(attachment.FileName).Name, 
                            fileProgressPercentageSegment, Context.User.Identity.Name, pageName);

                        ProcessFile(attachment, hubContext, fileProgressPercentageSegment, 
                                fileProgressPercentage);
                        fileProgressPercentage += fileProgressPercentagePortion;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e3)
    {

    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    var progress = $.connection.progressHub;
    console.log(progress);
    var hfUserAccount = document.getElementById("<%=hfUserAccount.ClientID %>");
    // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
    progress.client.AddProgress = function (fileName, message, percentage, userAccount, pageName) {

        if (userAccount === hfUserAccount.value && pageName === "CheckEFile.aspx") {

            ProgressBarModal("show", fileName + " " + message);
            document.getElementById("divProgress").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("divUpload").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("divProgress").style.width = percentage + "%";
            document.getElementById("lblPercentage").innerHTML = parseInt(percentage) + "%";
            $("#processingStatus").html("Please Wait. Checking files...");
            $('#ProgressMessage').width(percentage);
            if (percentage === "100%") {
                ProgressBarModal();
            }
        }
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
        console.log(connectionId);
    });

});
```

Here is my hub

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace IAACCESS.SignalR
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {
        static ProgressHub()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SignalR user is not registered in Client.Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946102/signalr-user-is-not-registered-in-client-users)

Comment: You can just use `Clients.Caller` to only respond to whoever called your method

Comment: Thank you @MindSwipe, however, for some reason 'Caller' property is not available for me in asp.net SignalR. Should I use another property? Thank you for your feedback

Comment: It is not clear where  and when you invoke AddProgress event for your clients. Can you send the code block that "hubContext.Clients.All.AddProgress(..)" call resides?

Comment: @NthDeveloper I just posted an entire event method, thank you

Comment: "hubContext.Clients.Client(hubContext.co).AddProgress(..)" There is such a line in your code. Then you know how to access to specific client but what is "hubContext.co"?

Comment: @NthDeveloper sorry I was away this weekend. Not sure I understood your question. hubContext does NOT give me anything specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, in my aspx I have

```
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
            console.log(connectionId);
            $('#<%=hfConnectionId.ClientID %>').val(connectionId);
        });
```

where I set the connection ID to a hidden field

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hfConnectionId" runat="server" />
```

And in code-behind I now have

```
hubContext.Clients.Client(hfConnectionId.Value).AddProgress("Currently processing: ", fn4, currentProgress, Context.User.Identity.Name, pageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to respond to whoever called your server side method, you can use the `Clients.Caller` property like so:

```cs
// Notice 'Clients.Caller' not 'Clients.All'
hubContext.Clients.Caller.AddProgress("Currently processing: ", new System.IO.FileInfo(attachment.FileName).Name, "0", Context.User.Identity.Name, pageName);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! It does seem helpful; however, unfortunately, the Caller property is NOT available. Is that because I am using WenForms, not MVC? Should I use AllExcept, Users, or Client methods instead, which are available?

Thank you once again for your help

Comment: Can you post your code where `hubContext` gets declared and assigned?

Comment: No you didn't. You added the `btnSubmit_Click` method, not where you are declaring `hubContext` and also not where you are assigning a value to `hubContext`

Comment: actually I did. It is within the code I posted. Just in case I just block quoted so it would stand out. Please let me know if you need additional info

Comment: So, just to check if I have it right, you have a ASP.NET application which is hosting the SignalR hub, and then you have a WinForms app which is invoking it, as well as you have JavaScript invoking it as well?

Comment: No, it is plain Asp.NET WebForms application (It doesn't have any WinForm items at all). It has SignalR hub class, it has C# codebehind with the button click event that contains the invocation of a SignalR context, and it has the aspx client page that contains the markup and the JavaScript code